# Load Custom Dataset (which is like 20 news group set) in Scikit for Classification of text documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run [this scikit example code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) for my custom dataset of Ted Talks. 
Each Directory is a Topic under which are text files which contain the description for each Ted Talk.

This is how my datasets tree structure is. As you see, each directory is a topic and below it are text files which carry description.

```
Topics/
|-- Activism
|   |-- 1149.txt
|   |-- 1444.txt
|   |-- 157.txt
|   |-- 1616.txt
|   |-- 1706.txt
|   |-- 1718.txt
|-- Adventure
|   |-- 1036.txt
|   |-- 1777.txt
|   |-- 2930.txt
|   |-- 2968.txt
|   |-- 3027.txt
|   |-- 3290.txt
|-- Advertising
|   |-- 3673.txt
|   |-- 3685.txt
|   |-- 6567.txt
|   `-- 6925.txt
|-- Africa
|   |-- 1045.txt
|   |-- 1072.txt
|   |-- 1103.txt
|   |-- 1112.txt
|-- Aging
|   |-- 1848.txt
|   |-- 2495.txt
|   |-- 2782.txt
|-- Agriculture
|   |-- 3469.txt
|   |-- 4140.txt
|   |-- 4733.txt
|   |-- 4939.txt
```

I have made my dataset in such form to resemble the 20news group whose tree structure is such:

```
20news-18828/
|-- alt.atheism
|   |-- 49960
|   |-- 51060
|   |-- 51119

|-- comp.graphics
|   |-- 37261
|   |-- 37913
|   |-- 37914
|   |-- 37915
|   |-- 37916
|   |-- 37917
|   |-- 37918
|-- comp.os.ms-windows.misc
|   |-- 10000
|   |-- 10001
|   |-- 10002
|   |-- 10003
|   |-- 10004
|   |-- 10005
```

In the [original code](http://pastebin.com/wx3pcArQ) (98-124), This is how training and testing data is loaded directly from scikit.

```
print("Loading 20 newsgroups dataset for categories:")
print(categories if categories else "all")

data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories,
                                shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                                remove=remove)

data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories,
                               shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                               remove=remove)
print('data loaded')

categories = data_train.target_names    # for case categories == None
def size_mb(docs):
    return sum(len(s.encode('utf-8')) for s in docs) / 1e6

data_train_size_mb = size_mb(data_train.data)
data_test_size_mb = size_mb(data_test.data)

print("%d documents - %0.3fMB (training set)" % (
    len(data_train.data), data_train_size_mb))
print("%d documents - %0.3fMB (test set)" % (
    len(data_test.data), data_test_size_mb))
print("%d categories" % len(categories))
print()

# split a training set and a test set
y_train, y_test = data_train.target, data_test.target
```

Since this dataset was available with Scikit, Its labels etc were all built in. 
For my case, I know how to load the dataset [(Line 84)](http://pastebin.com/1MGeL3D4):

```
dataset = load_files('./TED_dataset/Topics/')
```

I have no idea what I should do after that. I want to know how I should split this data in training and testing and generate these labels from my dataset:

```
data_train.data,  data_test.data
```

All in all, I just want to load my dataset, run it on this code error free. I have [uploaded the dataset here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0byAC8kZZPhYVJNVTdJa003U2M/view?usp=sharing) for those who might want to see it.

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761803/problems-loading-textual-data-with-scikit-learn) which speaks briefly about test-train loading. I also want to know how data_train.target_names should be fetched from my dataset.

Edit:

I tried to get the train and test which returns error:

```
dataset = load_files('./TED_dataset/Topics/')
train, test = train_test_split(dataset, train_size = 0.8)
```

Updated code is [here](http://pastebin.com/DcPCwaVS).

Comment: please reupload the dataset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.datasets import load_files

In [2]: from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

In [3]: bunch = load_files('./Topics')

In [4]: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(bunch.data, bunch.target, test_size=.4)

# Then proceed to train your model and validate.
```

Note that `bunch.target` is an array of integers which are the indices of the category names stored in `bunch.target_names`.

```
In [14]: X_test[:2]
Out[14]:
['Psychologist Philip Zimbardo asks, "Why are boys struggling?" He shares some stats (lower graduation rates, greater worries about intimacy and relationships) and suggests a few reasons -- and challenges the TED community to think about solutions.Philip Zimbardo was the leader of the notorious 1971 Stanford Prison Experiment -- and an expert witness at Abu Ghraib. His book The Lucifer Effect explores the nature of evil; now, in his new work, he studies the nature of heroism.',
 'Human growth has strained the Earth\'s resources, but as Johan Rockstrom reminds us, our advances also give us the science to recognize this and change behavior. His research has found nine "planetary boundaries" that can guide us in protecting our planet\'s many overlapping ecosystems.If Earth is a self-regulating system, it\'s clear that human activity is capable of disrupting it. Johan Rockstrom has led a team of scientists to define the nine Earth systems that need to be kept within bounds for Earth to keep itself in balance.']

In [15]: y_test[:2]
Out[15]: array([ 84, 113])

In [16]: [bunch.target_names[idx] for idx in y_test[:2]]
Out[16]: ['Education', 'Global issues']
```

Comment: Hey, the new documents which I will need to add as per the structure given by OP, each file should contain just some raw text belonging to that category, right? Is there any specific format in which the file should contain text, like with headers or footers, or just a para (or more) of raw text ?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger just raw text. However, you can use your custom function and/or preprocessors to transform any format (i.e.: JSON) to raw text suitable for text classification tasks.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you cite, the data set is downloaded from the sklearn package, and so are training and test sets (by using the `fetch_20newsgroup()` function). If you want to load your own dataset, you have to preprocess your data, vectorize the text, extract features and preferably put everything in nice numpy arrays or matrices. There are appropriate functions available which do that for you. The code you cite can't do anything with normal text files (calculations based on letters and words alone are difficult anyway ;-) ).

Once you've got so far, you define your training and your test set. Normally, one uses 90% of the data for training and 10% as test data. If you want to go even further, you can use 10-fold cross-validation in which you split your data into 10 parts, train on the first 9 and test on the 10th in the first round, train on the first 8 and the 10th and test on the 9th in the second round and so on and so forth.

Comment: So you say I should modify this code? : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py

Comment: You can use that as a model, but an even simpler script would do this as well. Just try to find your way around and let us know when you run into problems.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I followed the method above and it worked :)
When I have time, I'll try your method too. Thanks.